# Ordering an Eloquent ORM resultset based on the result of a method in a related model

Tags: php, algorithm, laravel, orm, eloquent

I'm trying to sort an Eloquent ORM call based on the result of a method defined in a related model. I'm using Laravel 5.

I want a list of `posts` including the posts `author`, `location`, `comments` and `counts` (which is a count of `views`, `upvotes` and `downvotes` for a post). I want the list sorted by `hotness`, which is not a field in the db (the result of a function).

In the `\App\Counts` model we have a method called `hotness()`

This method performs a calculation on an algorithm similar to the reddit algorithm [see below for details]

I have a an Eloquent ORM call:

```
$posts = \App\Post::with('author')
  ->with('location.city')
  ->with('comments')
  ->with('counts')
  ->paginate(20);
```

The `\App\Counts` model contains fields for `upvotes`, `downvotes`, `views`, and a few other variables that are used when calculating the hotness of the post.

I can add the `hotness` value to the array that comes back from the `counts` model when paginating (on the fly) by overriding the `toArray()` method in my model like this:

```
public function toArray()
{
    $array = parent::toArray();
    $array['hotness'] = $this->hotness();
    return $array;
}
```

While this is useful in its own right, I can't achieve my objective, which is to sort the ORM paginated result by each posts `hotness` rating.

Is there any way I can achieve this *without* having a cron go through all the posts and calculate the `hotness` for each post every x minutes?

I would ideally like to be able to just add

```
->orderBy('hotness')
```

or

```
->orderBy('counts.hotness')
```

but I have a feeling this might not be possible.

Any creative ideas around how to solve this?

---

*Hotness Algorithm for reference*

[image]

`T` is the time in seconds between when the post was made an the date of the first post on the website

`x` is the number of upvotes minus the number of downvotes

`y` is **-1** if `x < 0`, **0** if `x = 0` and **1** if `x > 0`

`z` is the absolute value of `x` and 1

Comment: try to override `orderBy` function according to your requirement under `Post` model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the functionality I'm looking for is not achievable.

I ended up persisting `hotness` to the `counts` table and update the value in the overriding `toArray()` method.

This allows me to `->orderBy('counts.hotness')`

In order to mitigate overhead I use a cache key that expires after 15 minutes so that I'm not calculating the `hotness` each time the `counts` model is converted to an array.

I settled on 15 minutes as this allows the `hotness` to be fresh enough for the purposes of this application.